# Configurei errado o WPS hide login. Como resolver?

Tags: wordpress

Eu instalei o plugin wps hide login e depois de instalado eu apenas o ativei, não alterei nenhuma configuração, abri uma nova aba e tentei entrar pela url padrão do wordpress que é wp-admin, ou apenas admin  e agora da o erro 404, provavelmente porque faz parte do sistema wps hide login e como ele atua, só que eu não tinha configurado, alterado a minha url padrão. Resumindo agora estou sem acessar o meu painel. Como eu faço para resolver isso? Preciso ter novamente o acesso ao painel para continuar o meu trabalho, como é apenas um projeto beta, um teste, estou fazendo no localhost utilizando o Xampp.
Espero que essas informações sobre meu problema tenham ajudado e também espero a colaboração de todos. Agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está no seu servidor local á duas maneira de resolver isso.

A primeira e mais fácil é envés de acessar com `/wp-admin` use `/login`

Ou caso de errado com o `/login`, como você está no `localhost` da para apenas entrar na pasta do projeto e deletar o plugin apagando seu diretorio: `/meusite/wp-content/` selecione a pasta do `wps-hide-login` e delete ela, mas essa opção não é recomendada em *servidores remotos*

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema